# UITableViewCell present individually

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Is there a way to present the cells in a UITableView one by one? Kind of like an animation where each row is presented after a 0.5 sec delay from the previous row?

I have tried using NSTimer and the delay method with a selector and both don't quite work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = false

      **NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5)**
       return cell




    **NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "returnCell", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)**

    func returnCell(){
        return cell
    }
}
```

Those are the two ways I tried

Comment: Show the code you have attempted.  It should be possible with an NSTimer and the appropriate manipulation of the table data source

Comment: Not by delaying inside `cellForRow...`!  (You should **never** delay inside code that's running in the main UI thread.)  What you'd have to do is have something in the background keep modifying your dataSource and re-issuing `reloadData` (or `reloadRows...`, or doing `insertRows...withRowAnimation`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve the delay in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - you need to either manipulate the underlying table data source or at least give the impression of doing so.  Assuming your table data is in an array called "data" one approach would be -

```
var cellCount=0
var timer?

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (data.count >0) {
        let self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector:"incrementCellCount", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func incrementCellCount() {
  self.cellCount++

  if (self.cellCount == data.count) {
     self.timer!.invalidate()
     self.timer=nil
  }

  self.tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.cellCount-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}


func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int
{
   return self.cellCount;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't reload the table each time. There would be no animation. Use `insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that but I was too lazy to work out the Swift syntax, but you have shamed me into doing it now ;)